# MouseHover and MouseLeave don't work when the control is invisible

Tags: c#, button, visible, mousehover

For some reason MouseHover and MouseLeave functions behave really strange. All I need to do is, when the cursor is over the "button", I want to make the button visible and when the cursor leaves the button, I want to make it invisible. Whatever I try I couldn't make it work. It seems like Mouse events not working when the control object is invisible.

```
private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   button1.Visible = true;
}

private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Please see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/03/23/558887.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That’s how it works. One option is to continue handling the button's `MouseLeave` event the same way, and handle `MouseMove` for its parent (I assume the form):

```
private void Form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (button1.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) && !button1.Visible) {
        button1.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the terse comment suggests, invisible objects are not recognized by the mouse, because they "aren't there".

Answer (score 2):

Put the button onto a `Panel` that's sized and positioned to exactly contain the button. Then hook `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave` on the panel. Show/hide the button; leave the panel always visible so it can get the mouse events.

Answer (score 1):

That's how it works; invisible controls do not respond to mouse events.

How about reconsidering your design?  An invisible control that only appears when the mouse scrolls over it just screams "hard to use".  I could understand a few child controls appearing when hovering over a parent container or control, but not a lone button, invisible until found purely by luck.  You could always just wrap the button in another container and handle the container's mouse events.