# Show/Hide button on MouseOver

Tags: c#, button, hide

I have a button on my WinForms app that I want to be invisible until the user moves his mouse over the button. Then they could click it. If the mouse leaves the button, it needs to be hidden again. The button.Visible parameter makes the button completely inaccessible and disables the mouse over. Any ideas or other button parameters I could use?

This currently does not work:

```
private void settingButton_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    settingButton.Visible = true;
}

private void settingButton_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    settingButton.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I take it the user wont know the location of the button until they move the mouse over it?

Comment: yup. or only those that i want to know. it's for an app that doesn't require a lot of user input, maybe updating some settings once in a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue was brought up and answered here:

[C# WinForms MouseHover and MouseLeave problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513601/c-sharp-winforms-mousehover-and-mouseleave-problem)

```
private void Form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if(settingButton.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) && !settingButton.Visible) {
        settingButton.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: But to be clear you need to continue handling the button's MouseLeave event.