# C# WinForms - How to make TextBox visible only when mouse hovers on it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this TextBox that is invisible by default. Its location is lower left corner of the window/form. When I move my mouse to the lower left of the form, I want the TextBox to show up, so I can type some things in it. But, as soon as I move my mouse away from the TextBox, it should become invisible again.

I have tried the following.

```
    private void magicTextBox_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        magicTextBox.Visible = true;
    }

    private void magicTextBox_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        magicTextBox.Visible = false;
    }
```

The problem is, once it becomes invisible, it doesn't become visible again when you hover in the lower left corner.

Comment: As it is no longer shows no mouseevents will now be triggered. So: You need to code the mousemove (or -hover) event __of the form (or parent__ of the textbox). For this you need to store the textbox.Bounds rectangle and then show it and set focus to it. Use tbBound.Contains(e.Location) in the form_mouseMove or hover event!

Comment: it doesnt become visible again because when its invisible its not receiving the events, put up an empty label or panel where you expect it to be and swap them to make it work (eg its visible when the textbox isnt)

Comment: @TaW I don't know how to do that or what you are saying exactly.

Comment: @BugFinder an empty label would be incredibly small in size and hard to find with mouse

Comment: Maybe you can remove the borders and the text, and give it the same color as the parent it is on, so the TextBox is still there but only seems invisible, like camuflage

Comment: _an empty label would be incredibly small_ No.You can turn off AutoSize and give it any size. But you still need the same amount of code as when using the Parent.

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Comment: Apparently, `MouseLeave` doesn't work as good for `TextBox` as it does for `Button`. So, I suggest to work with `Form.MouseMove` only. Here's a [runnable code example](https://gist.github.com/defaultlocale/2955a5d18be5fe06eab5ae95e7c12a1e), and here's [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqEQ4.gif). I assumed that you'd want to always show the textbox if it has a focus.

Comment: @EsAMe not really if you turn off autosize it stays whatever size you set it to be

Answer (score 0):

This issue was brought up and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513601/c-sharp-winforms-mousehover-and-mouseleave-problem).

You need to add `MouseMove` event on the Form.

```
private void Form_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  if (magicTextBox.Bounds.Contains(e.Location) && !magicTextBox.Visible) {
    //Do something...
 }
}
```